# how to convert a number into a timestamp?

Tags: php, time, phpmyadmin, timestamp

how would I use php to convert a number into a timestamp (specifically minutes)?

i'm using timestamps in my database, for example `00:01:30` and `00:00:30`

but the people i'm writing this for have the habit (and requested) that they just are able to enter `30` or `60` or `75`. on my end, i need to somehow convert these to `00:00:30`, `00:01:00` and `00:01:15` respectively.

how would i go about doing this? i know about `strtotime()` and `date()` but I can't seem to figure out how to take the number and convert it...

thanks

Comment: What are you asking here? Do you want to know how to do integer division and modulo in php, or is there something more to the questions?

Comment: But its not time your working with, its division of an int

Comment: You may have to manually parse parts of it. For example if it is always in minutes, use $hours = $min/60; $minutes = $min%60;

Comment: ok, so there is no built in php function that can convert a number to minutes... i have to manually do it myself?

Comment: Is the input minutes or seconds? I wrote my answer assuming minutes, but re-reading the question I'm now thinking that the input is actually seconds.

Comment: i'm afraid it could be both. both `75` and `1:15` are expected to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one trick to easily convert such int to time:

```
$time = gmdate('H:i:s', 75); // 00:01:15
```

This works, because gmdate will always convert seconds from `1970-01-01 00:00:00`, so it wil produce correct result for all integers below 86400

Comment: this is working great when the user enters seconds. i can't be sure they won't ever enter minutes...

Comment: would a viable solution be to check if a `:` is present in a string, then skip this conversion. because i'm betting some people will enter `75` and others will enter `1:15`...?

Comment: yes, but then `1:15` will turn into `01:15:00`, not `00:01:15`

Comment: how come if I enter `120` instead of `75` it gives me `1:00` instead of `2:00`?

Comment: my bad, `m` stands for months not minutes... should be `i` instead

Answer (score 2):

If the input is only minutes, rather than dealing with strtotime, you might want to just convert it to the string manually. For example:

```
<?php
  $minutes = 75;
  $timestring = sprintf('%2d:%2d:%2d', floor($minutes/60), ($minutes%60), 0);
  echo 'Time: '.$timestring;
?>
```

This would print out `01:15:00`. From your question it looks like the minutes are in the last column, but I'm showing my solution with a more standard format.

**Edit: including the result and using a more appropriate example**:

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php). For example if you know the starting time you can enter than and then just add 30, 60, or 90 to the minutes column.

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP is new enough (5.3.x), use the DateTime class, and then either create a time from the start of the day, and then add 75 minutes, or even use the built in formats to convert from the passed time.